# get value from multiple buttons

Tags: javascript

How can I get the value of the button that the user clicked. I tried this but it doesn't work

```
for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        var x = document.getElementsByClassName("button")[i].onclick() = function(){
            console.log(x);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("button").click(function() {
    alert($(this).html()); // for the text in button tag. for value in button tag use $(this).val()
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="up" value="up">button up</button>
<button id="down" value="down">button down</button>
```

if you don't want to use jquery and use only pure javascript you can do following:

```html
<button id="up" value="up" onclick="alert(this.value)">button up</button><!-- for value -->
<button id="down" onclick="alert(this.innerHTML)">button down</button><!-- for text in tag -->
```